# Word for "cost of delayed choice"

Tags: single-word-requests

In my daily work, I've noticed a concept that keeps coming up.

Suppose we're making an app, and we have to make a decision whether to add X or not.  X is difficult to add.  BUT, we might eventually discover that we need it.  A critical part of the decision becomes *how much harder it will become* to add X later, rather than now.  It'd be nice to have a word for this value.  Let's call the word "fooble".  (Hopefully that's not already a word.)  So, for example:

1. "Well, we could add Doohickeys now, but it'd be hard, and it's pretty low fooble, anyway.  We might as well wait."  Meaning, the cost later minus the cost now is small.  It isn't going to be harder later.  (So we might as well wait and see.)
2. "Yeah, it's hard to add Dinglehoppers now, but its fooble is huge.  We'd basically have to start all over."  Meaning, the cost later minus the cost now is large.  It'll get harder and harder to add as time goes on.  (So if we think we're going to have to add it eventually anyway, we should add it now and save ourselves the trouble.)

What word could replace "fooble", in the above sentences?  AKA, a word for "the cost of delaying a choice or action" or "the cost of an action taken later minus the cost of the same action instead taken now."  A single word would be preferable, but a short phrase would probably be acceptable.  (Probably better than walking around the office saying "fooble".)  Currently my best candidate is "delay cost", but that could be a bit ambiguous, and I'd like to know if there's a commonly accepted word or phrase.

A noun makes the most sense to me, but an adjective ("it's very fooble") could work, if it's a very good fit.

Comment: I know precisely what you are driving at in terms of systems design, build and implementation costs. There is often a significant tension between those tightly managing a budget right now and those looking to the future and thinking “But it will be more expensive if we have to do it later!”.  But, unfortunately, I have no ideas about what terminology to use to explain this succinctly.  “Fooble” makes me think of “doable” but that’s as far as I get.